# Why are we named 12 days after birth?

Tags: scripture, belief, rituals, practice, culture

Including myself, many of my family members got their names 12 days after their birth, a day called *Namakarana*. This is done via a ritual, for example in *Nepalese* tradition (My ethnicity) we have an extra tradition called *Nwaran*.

Why do we give names to our newborn on their twelfth (some at eleventh) day? and any references to the scriptures?

Comment: The first 12 days  period after babies birth is  considered inauspicious for both mother and baby OR " Sutaka".Naming ceremony is conducted after that period , or based on a priest or an astrologers advice.

Comment: yes, it's a period of uncleanliness, ashoucha, or theetu. For both birth and death in a family, 10 or 12 days after that, auspicious things are avoided.